# Trying to get the Menu and Sub menu in Horizontal

Tags: html, css

I want menu and sub menu both in **horizontal**.This is the code i tried main menu in horizontal.When i hover the `mainmenu` i want **`submenu`** also in horizontal.

Any body know how to solve this

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5b8t/)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/b5b8t/17/)**
Basically, you need to use absolute positioning to take the secondary menu and position it directly below the main menu.

```
ul li ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li ul li a{
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li ul{
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: I have a small doubt, If i select the tab it lists clearly, but when it lists it should highlight the above tab where we have selected, so what i want to do for that??

Answer (score 5):

Add `position:absolute`:

**css**

```
ul li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute; /*Add this */
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5b8t/6/)

Also add `left:8px` if you want left align like this:

```
ul li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left:8px; /* Add this too for left align*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5b8t/11/)

Comment: An explanation, could be better. :)

Comment: Here is also an example with all menus have childrens elements http://jsfiddle.net/b5b8t/16/

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
**HTML:**

<ul id="level-1">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li>
<a href="#">Products</a>
<ul id="level-2">
<li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

**CSS:**


 ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul#level-1 > li{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: #939393;
}
ul li ul{
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul{
    display: inline-flex;
    width: auto;/* display the dropdown */
}

ul li:hover ul#level-2 li{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```